# Why do I have to state networks twice in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm a bit confused. In docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
services:
  eliko:
    image: irmscher/eliko:v1
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=eliko
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:eliko.bloggercraft.com
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
    networks:
      - proxy
```

Why do I have to specify network twice? First time in `networks: proxy` and 2nd time within the services `networks: -proxy`?

I actually have created 'proxy' network with `docker network create proxy` beforehand. I thought `networks:` within the docker-compose CREATE networks, so I decided to remove it and only leave the network name within my services (eliko) header. But then I have received an error: `ERROR: Service "eliko" uses an undefined network "proxy"`

So my question is.. what does this exactly do:

```
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Since, as far as I understand, this:

```
    networks:
      - proxy
```

connects to a network, so the previous supposed to create the network? What if I create a network with `docker network create`, is it identical or?

A bit confused here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level `networks` stanza is telling docker-compose "these are the networks that exist".  Without that, docker-compose wouldn't know what to do when you try to connect your `eliko` container to the `proxy` network.  You'd get this:

```
ERROR: Service "eliko" uses an undefined network "proxy"
```

Remember that in the standard case, networks in docker-compose are prefixed with the project name.  If you have a non-external network, like this:

```
version: "3"
networks:
  proxy:
services:
  eliko:
    image: irmscher/eliko:v1
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=eliko
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:eliko.bloggercraft.com
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
    networks:
      - proxy
```

Then compose will actually create a network named `project_proxy` (where `project` is by default the name of the directory that contains your `docker-compose.yml`).  It's only because you've declared the network to be `external` that compose knows you want to use an existing network.